# Access a text file from clipboard in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard

I try to create a macro for excel which reads the content of a text file, creates a new workbook of it and than uses a specific section inside the created workbook. To be able to get easy access to needed columns, I worked with Workbook.OpenText. But instead of inserting a fix path to my file, i would like to get the path of the file I copied to the clipboard. My Problem is, I don't know how to get access to the clipboard of windows. I found a tutorial on working with the clipboard [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx), but i can't get access to the expected library. I also searched also on my computer for a file called FM20.DLL like explained in this [forum](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-add-vba-reference-microsoft-forms-2-0-object-library-t3365334.html) but couldn't find anything.
Here is my code:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\path\to.txt", Origin _
        :=-535, StartRow:=16, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1 _
        ), Array(14, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(68, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022245/get-text-from-clipboard-using-gettext-avoid-error-on-empty-clipboard Let me know if you still want help?

Comment: I still have a problem, accessing the file from the clipboard with OpenText. Inside the Clipboard there is no path but OpenText just works with a path. And I don't know another method, how to open a textfile in the sameway, so that the content will be formated like in my code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem on a different way. I don't use the OpenText method anymore. I used following code to insert from clipboard into my worksheet:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This isn't the answer of my question, but looks much easier to me as the answer before. It also worked, but i had to import library manually and write a lot more code. 
The way i have to access the code is now another. I jump from line to line, get save the line in a variable, delete the whitespace from the string

```
stringLine = Replace(Range("A" & row).Value, " ", "")
```

and create an array with the several values by using

```
anArray = Split(stringLine, "|")
```

Anyway, thank you for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you do not need any user form at all**

[image: STEP 1]

[image: STEP 2]

[image: STEP 3]

**Now add the code**

```
Sub ShowClipboardData()
    'In the VBA editor, go to Tools, References, and set a reference to the "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library"
    Dim MyDataObject As DataObject
    Set MyDataObject = New DataObject
    MyDataObject.GetFromClipBoard
    MyDataObject.GetText
    MsgBox CStr(MyDataObject.GetText)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I created the UserForm but can't delete it like in the second pic. Maybe you just can explain to me, way this has to be done.
Furthermore, I have the german Version of the VBA editor. So don't know exactly how to set the Reference. Is it the big list that starts with "Global"? Because I can't find the library in this list.

Comment: You could also manually add reference file going to ``"X:\WINDOWS\system32\FM20.DLL"``, ``X`` is the drive where windows installed.

Comment: I just solved the problem, inserting the library. I haven't stopped my script, so it wasn't possible to create a reference....
You script works, but its only for plain text that will be copied from anywhere. This doesn't work with a hole File. Is it just possible to get the path too?