# Paste text to textbox via button VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I want a copy and a paste button in MS Excel, the copy button looks like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MyData As New DataObject
MyData.SetText TextBox1.Text
MyData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Now, how can I make/code a PASTE button in a similar fashion?

Comment: where are both the textboxes?

Comment: in a userform excel textboxname(txtKordinatat)

Comment: both are on the same form?

Comment: No I do not want to copy from textbox1 in TextBox2 //. I just need a paste text into the textbox where I'm writing

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the post from [Get text from clipboard using GetText - avoid error on empty clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022245/get-text-from-clipboard-using-gettext-avoid-error-on-empty-clipboard) helped me arrive at the solution that I was looking for.

```
    Dim DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject 

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Get data from the clipboard.
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    '~~> Get clipboard contents
    Me.txtKordinatat.Value = DataObj.GetText(1)

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox "Data on clipboard is not text or is empty"
```

Comment: ++ For figuring it out yourself ;)